# How to draw a list of images with circular border in dart canvas?

Tags: flutter, canvas, paint, flutter-canvas

I need to draw a list of images with canvas, and I need that each image has a circular border:
expected:

[image]

but what I implemented is:

[image]

my code is:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < participants.length; i++) {
    Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer<ui.Image>();
    Image networkImage = Image.network(participants[i]?.avatar ?? "");
    networkImage.image
        .resolve(const ImageConfiguration())
        .addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
      canvas.drawImageNine(info.image, const Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
          Rect.fromLTRB(10+(i*20), 50, (participants.length * 20 )+ 50, 100), Paint());
      completer.complete(info.image);
    }));
  }
```

I use `canvas.clipPath()` before `canvas.drawImage()` too:

```
   Path path = Path()..addOval(const Rect.fromLTWH(10, 50, 50+(i*50), 50));
   canvas.clipPath(path);
```

it clipped whole the list:

[image]

Please give me some help if you have any ideas.

Comment: do you want the solution with canvas only? I think using flutter widgets will be better than drawing it manually with canvas api.

Comment: Yes, because for some reason, we used Paint, so I need a solution using canvas.

Comment: check  `Canvas.save` / `Canvas.restore`

Comment: could you explain more? @pskink

Comment: before you call `clipPath` call `save` and after drawing one image call `restore`

Comment: and simply use `canvas.drawImage` not `canvas.drawImageNine`

Comment: canvas.save() and restore works for me, thanks a lot.